# view with navigationController over tabBarController

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

How I can open new view over `UITabBar` and with working `UINavigationController`?

```
self.navigationController?.pushViewController(view, animated: true)
```

Example:
[image]

Comment: Don't repost your questions. If needed, update your previous question with further details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`UIViewControllers` have a `hidesBottomBarWhenPushed` property that you can set in the attributes tab in `Interface Builder`.